# Evolution versions of applications

Tags: web-applications, versioning

Don't understand some things about evolution versions of some applications. Please tell me why, for example, firefox 26.0b1 released earlier than 25.0? What it means to "x" version? (5.x)? release candidate (rc)? Alpha? Beta?

Comment: You might want to read: http://semver.org/

Answer (score 2):

The `b` in `26.0b1` stands for `beta` and according to their [release process](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease) and [release calendar](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar) we can see why the beta for the next version is released earlier than the release version. `central`, `aurora`, `beta` and `release` are stages in their [deployment pipeline](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DeploymentPipeline.html).

Since version `4.0` (i think), they have adopted the [release early, release often](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Release_early,_release_often) philosophy, hence the rapid increase of major version number over a shorter period of time (compared to the `0.1` - `4.0` release window). The `Chrome` team uses the same philosophy.

The `x` could stand as a placeholder for all the minor versions in the major version `5`, but this really depends on who is developing the application, since the versioning strategy is often different from company to company.